# MacOSX Custom Webkit view + Flash content with clickable links

Tags: cocoa, webkit

Symptom:

View the flash website with any browser, the links inside the flash content work and launch a new window
view the flash with my custom WebView, click the same links. No response.

I tried delegating "decidePolicyForNewWindowAction" and "decidePolicyForNavigationAction" but ironically, these are only called after I launch a URL from my code, NOT as a response to the user clicking the link from the page.

I am sure the fact this is a flash app content has something to do with it. I don't know how to resolve this. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set a `UIDelegate` for the WebView, and then implement `- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request` in that delegate.

If you then set a policy delegate for the new `WebView` that you return (that WebView can be in a hidden window), the delegate method that will be called is:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)aWebView 
    decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation 
                            request:(NSURLRequest *)request 
                              frame:(WebFrame *)frame
                   decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener`
```

The URL to which the Flash app is trying to send the window is in the `WebActionOriginalURLKey` of the `actionInformation` dictionary, and you can at that point decide if you want the navigation to proceed, or send an ignore to the `WebPolicyDecisionListener` and handle the URL some other way.

Comment: Is there no way to preview the URL BEFORE having to create/return a new view? What I really want to do at this point is just spawn an external browser for the link URL.

It's kind of a chicken/egg problem here. I don't want to create a new view for the URL, but i can't launch it externally because I don't know what it is until I create a view for it (request is always NIL with the "createWebViewWithRequest" method)

Comment: Ah, yes... it's a bit convoluted, I must admit.

Comment: solved it, or rather bypassed it, with that flag i mentioned in the last comment. Thanks for your help!